# UNIX TIMESTAMP while making curl request

Tags: curl

I want to pass 1 hour earlier time in unix timestamp in my request:

> curl -X PUT  -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d
>   '{"time":UNIX_TIME_STAMP-1 HOUR}' url

How can I generate and pass **UNIX_TIME_STAMP-1 HOUR** while making a curl request?

This gives me current time - 1 hour, but I am unable to pass it as param:

date -d '1 hour ago' "+%s"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can subshell date

```
curl -X PUT -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"time":'"`date -d '1 hour ago' +%s`"'}' url
```